# Prove positive definite matrix and determinant inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are two real symmetric matrices and $A \succeq B$ (that means $A-B$ is a psd matrix), does that hold $|A|\ge|B|$? and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not. Consider, e.g. $A=I_2$ and $B=-2I_2$ with $\det A=1<4=\det B$.

**Edit:** However, the statement is true if $B$ is positive semidefinite. That $A\succeq B$ implies that $A$ is positive semidefinite too. If $\det B=0$, the statement obviously holds. If $\det B>0$, then both $A$ and $B$ are positive definite. Hence $A\succeq B$ implies that $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}\succeq I$ and in turn $\det(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})\ge 1$, i.e. $\det A\ge\det B$. (In fact, if $A\succeq B\succ0$, we have $\lambda_k(A)\ge\lambda_k(B)$ for every $k$. This is a property of *positive definite ordering*, but we do not need this fact here.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. $ $

Comment: Thanks! if A⪰B≻0, we have λk(A)≥λk(B) for every k. How to prove that?

Comment: @Nature4D This is a direct consequence of [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

Comment: @user1551 Thanks. I only know some basic of linear algebra.... :-(