# $A$, $B$, and $A-B$ are non negative definite matrices. How to show that $\det(A) \geq \det(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, determinant, linear-matrix-inequality

Suppose $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are non negative definite matrices. We have already know that $A-B$ is also non negative definite. How to show that $\det(A) \geq \det(B)$, if $\det(A)$ means the determinant of matrix $A$?

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you found this question, what you have tried so far, and any other thoughts you might have on the question.

Comment: There's a proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404965/prove-positive-definite-matrix-and-determinant-inequality also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539312/determinant-inequality-positive-definite-matrices and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515308/if-a-and-b-are-linear-transformations-on-a-finite-dimensional-inner-product

Comment: And probably several others.

Comment: Thank you so much!